# How to color the terminal (terminator)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, terminator

Sometimes I see terminals colored like this:

[image]

But mine (terminator on Ubuntu) is just black and white most of the time. How to make it colored like in the example?

Comment: You mean the output in the terminal? That's just depending on the application. Some applications output with color, some don't. For example, `grep` has the `--color` flag.

Answer (score 7):

- Open terminator

  - right click in the terminal window  -- you will see menu
  - Choose Preferences
  - Choose Profiles
  - choose Colors
  - Select your color theme you wish
  - Or edit the colors manually as you wish

hope it helps you

Comment: That's nice, but how do people achieve different colors base on the context rather than just making everything a particular color?

Comment: @LonnieBest you can set up different profiles with different schemes associated with each. For example I have a "regular" profile with my personal color scheme, a "work" profile with extra highlighting on important output, and a "root" profile that clearly reminds me Im using root.  
I think its quite intuitive how to set it up,  Preferences >> Profile >> add

Answer (score 0):

Edit `~/.bashrc` and un-comment line:

```
# force_color_prompt=yes
```

to be:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

save then execute `source ~/.bashrc`